# Javascript - Using a string array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

Here's a beginner JS question. I'm making a simple app that takes the days I  work, the day of the week and then alert's me if I work today.

```
//
var daysIWork = [
  'Wednesday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday',
];

var dayToday = 'Saturday'; // I'll be changing this to a more advanced method, getDay? When I've figured out how to post this correctly.

for (var i = 0; i < daysIWork.length; i++) {
   console.log(daysIWork[i])
}; // This posts the array correctly, yay.
```

This is where I'm stuck. If I input a number that matches an array number ie `[1]` instead of `[i]`, the statement will pop up `true`. However with the code below, it always turns out `false`.

```
if (dayToday === daysIWork[i]) {
   alert ('Noooo, you work today!');
} else {
   alert ("Yes, you don't work today!");
}
```

I know how to get it working using the array call `[1]` `[2]` etc but I can't get it to read a whole array and come back as `true`.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you have your `if`?  It works fine when placing it in the loop: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayntsL2/)

Comment: Rereading the question you actually want to detect if the day `dayToday` is within `daysIWork` or not. So you actually would use `daysIWork.indexOf(dayToday) !== -1` to check if it is in the array. For IE 8 and before your would need to use a polyfill  [MSN: Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Comment: Ok that works but it's going through the whole array and posting. IE my 4 items, returns 3 false and 1 true which makes sense in the current code. However I just want one true and one false to come back. If dayToday and a day in the daysIWork match up post true if not post one false alert.

Comment: So that would go within the for or if niese.

Comment: Whats wrong with the `daysIWork.indexOf(dayToday) !== -1` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/efsy19nu/  I'm getting back four trues.

Comment: In your fiddle, you test if `Sunday` is a workday (in the list `daysIWork`) and that four times, why should it return any thing different for one of those tests? You don't have to use  `daysIWork.indexOf(dayToday) !== -1` in the loop.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efsy19nu/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var daysIWork = [
      'Wednesday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday',
      'Sunday',
    ];

    var dayToday = 'Saturday';


    if (daysIWork.indexOf(dayToday) > 0) {
      console.log('boo');
    } else {
      console.log('yay')
    }
```